# Is there a way to change a few columns and keep all other columns, and not assign by reference or use copy?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

Consider example data:

```
tmp_dt <- data.table(a = 1:3, b = 2:4, c = 3:5)
tmp_dt
#    a b c
# 1: 1 2 3
# 2: 2 3 4
# 3: 3 4 5
```

As example, take the negative of column `b`, and pass this new data table into a computation, without modifying `tmp_dt` in place. I know one way of doing it is `copy(tmp_dt)[, b := -b][]`, which produces:

```
#    a  b c
# 1: 1 -2 3
# 2: 2 -3 4
# 3: 3 -4 5
```

However, I do not like this as I find demarcating the left and right brackets for `copy` messy when you wish to do something complicated to `tmp_dt` first, for example, `copy(tmp_dt)[do complicated stuff][...]` vs `copy(tmp_dt[do complicated stuff])[...]`.

Put a different way, I would like to be able to read the order of operations from left to right like in a `dplyr` chain: `tmp_dt %>% do complicated stuff %>% copy`. One way to do this, without preserving column order, is:

```
tmp_dt[, c(.(b = -b), .SD), .SDcols = -'b']
#     b a c
# 1: -2 1 3
# 2: -3 2 4
# 3: -4 3 5
```

Does anyone know of more elegant `data.table` approaches that does, or improves on this?

Comment: essentially I would like a `.keep_all` argument.

Comment: `f(DT %>% copy %>% .[yadayada])` ? I sometimes do this, loading magrittr for the pipes.

Comment: Does it have to specifically `magittr`? I've tried something like this with `dplyr` loaded and it never seems to end well.

Comment: It always works for me with magrittr. For my use, dplyr is not needed when data.table is loaded, and besides it has namespace conflicts, so I haven't tried it for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either,

```
 tmp_dt[, .SD][, b := -b]
```

or simply,

```
 tmp_dt[, .(a, b = -b, c)]
```

Comment: Thanks, the first solution is pretty neat. I wasn't aware that chaining with a `:=` later on will not modify the starting table `tmp_dt`. The second solution is cumbersome in the case where there are many columns.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work and is less clumsy than my first attempt in the OP, plus preserves original column ordering:

```
tmp_dt[, copy(.SD)[, b := -b]][]

# a  b c
# 1: 1 -2 3
# 2: 2 -3 4
# 3: 3 -4 5
```

Manipulation of `.SD` is explained in [FAQ 4.5](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#cannot-change-value-of-locked-binding-for-.sd):

> .SD is locked by design. See ?data.table. If you’d like to manipulate .SD before using it, or returning it, and don’t wish to modify DT using :=, then take a copy first (see ?copy), e.g.,

Comment: Although, I don't know what the memory implications of this is.